# Properties of a line lying wholly on a surface

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image: check this(part1)]

[image: part2]

Why is the coefficient of $r^2$ and $r$ equal to zero if a line lies wholly on a surface? (see pics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of plugging the parametrization of the line into the conicoid equation is a polynomial in $r$ which is identically equal to zero.

If a polynomial is identically equal to zero, then each of its coefficients is identically equal to zero.